# How to print in the same line print_big('j'), print_big('o'),print_big('j'),print_big('o') in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print in the same line `print_big('j')`, `print_big('o')`, `print_big('j')`, `print_big('o')` to have `JOJO`.

```
print(patterns[pattern], end= '')

def print_big(letter):
    patterns={0:'  *',1:'   * ',2:' *  *',3:'*    *',4:'******',5:'****',6:'* ***',7:' *  ',
            8:'*  *',9:'*   ',10:'**   *',11:'* *  *',12:'*  * *',13:'*   **',14:'***',
            15:'*     *',16:'* * * *',17:'*  *  *',18:'*******',19:' *   * ',20:' ****',
            21:'      *',22:' *****',23:'**** ',24:'  **  ',25:'    *',26:' *** '}

    alphabet={'A':[24,2,4,3,3],'B':[5,3,5,3,5],'C':[20,9,9,9,20],'D':[5,3,3,3,5],'E':[4,9,4,9,4], 'F':[4,9,5,9,9],
             'G':[20,9,6,3,20],'H':[3,3,4,3,3],'I':[14,7,7,7,14],'J':[5,1,1,1,0],'K':[3,8,7,8,3],'L':[9,9,9,9,4],
             'M':[15,16,17,15],'N':[10,11,12,13],'O':[20,3,3,20],'P':[5,3,5,9,9],'Q':[20,3,12,22,21],'R':[5,3,5,3,3],
             'S':[20,9,24,25,23],'T':[18,1,1,1,1,],'U':[3,3,3,4],'V':[15,15,15,19,1],'W':[15,17,16,15],
             'X':[15,19,1,19,15],'Y':[15,19,1,1,1],'Z':[4,25,26,7,4,]}
    for pattern in alphabet[letter.upper()]:
        print(patterns[pattern])
```

Expected result `JOJO` actual result

```
J
O
J
O
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is broken because you construct every single letter by 4-5 lines. If you wanted to write letters in one line, you would have to print the 1st line of every character, then line break, then the 2nd line, etc.

You are unable to do this atm because your letters are not equally spaced. `U` and `O` are only 4 lines high, all others 5. The individual lines vary between 3 (`0:'  *'`) and 7 (`18:'*******'`) width. If you mix and match letters this will warp your text.

You need to create a better mapping, ideally with euqally width characters. Then you need to get the 1st line of each characters in your word, print it using `end = '', sep = " "` then add a line break, then print the second line.

---

```
def print_big(word):
    # fixes for overall pattern width - all exactly 7 letters wide
    #            1234567      1234567       1234567      1234567      1234567     1234567
    patterns={0:'  *    ', 1:'   *   ', 2:' *  *  ', 3:'*    * ', 4:'****** ', 5:'****   ', 
              6:'* ***  ', 7:' *     ', 8:'*  *   ', 9:'*      ',10:'**   * ',11:'* *  * ',
              12:'*  * *',13:'*   ** ',14:'***    ',15:'*     *',16:'* * * *',17:'*  *  *',
              18:'******',19:' *   * ',20:' ****  ',21:'      *',22:' ***** ',23:'****   ',
              24:'  **  ',25:'    *  ',26:' ***   '}

    # fixes for O and U wich had only 4 lines, not 5
    alp = {'A':[24,2,4,3,3],   'B':[5,3,5,3,5],  'C':[20,9,9,9,20],  'D':[5,3,3,3,5],
           'E':[4,9,4,9,4],    'F':[4,9,5,9,9],  'G':[20,9,6,3,20],  'H':[3,3,4,3,3],
           'I':[14,7,7,7,14],  'J':[5,1,1,1,0],  'K':[3,8,7,8,3],    'L':[9,9,9,9,4],
           'M':[15,16,17,15],  'N':[10,11,12,13],'O':[20,3,3,3,20],  'P':[5,3,5,9,9],
           'Q':[20,3,12,22,21],'R':[5,3,5,3,3],  'S':[20,9,24,25,23],'T':[18,1,1,1,1,],
           'U':[3,3,3,3,4],    'V':[15,15,15,19,1],                  'W':[15,17,16,15],
           'X':[15,19,1,19,15],'Y':[15,19,1,1,1],'Z':[4,25,26,7,4,]}

    # generate the needed indexes for all letters line-wise
    lines = zip(*[alp[c] for c in word.upper()])
    print(list(lines))

    for what in lines:
        for w in what:
            print(patterns[w], end="")
        print()


print_big("JOJO")
```

Output:

```
# zipped lines, indexes of each tuple are one line for all letters)
[(5, 20, 5, 20), (1, 3, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1, 3), (0, 20, 0, 20)]


****    ****  ****    ****  
   *   *    *    *   *    * 
   *   *    *    *   *    * 
   *   *    *    *   *    * 
  *     ****    *     ****
```

See [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for what it does exactly.

You need to check the other letters if they print nicely and adjust `patterns` if not.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks a bunch for your help, I try and it works great.